# How can I modify a type in ack?

Tags: ack

I know how to set a new type.  What I want to do is modify an existing type.  I want to add haml files to the ruby type.  I could probably use --set-type and redefine the ruby type but I don't know how to redefine it and still include files called 'Rakefile' and files where the first line indicates that it is an executable Ruby script (First line matches /^#!.*\bruby/)

Here is the existing documentation for the ruby type:

```
ruby         .rb .rhtml .rjs .rxml .erb .rake .spec; Rakefile; First line matches /^#!.*\bruby/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three arguments that let you work with type definitions.  From `ack --help`:

```
File type specification:
  --type-set=TYPE:FILTER:ARGS   Files with the given ARGS applied to the given
                                FILTER are recognized as being of type TYPE.
                                This replaces an existing definition for TYPE.
  --type-add=TYPE:FILTER:ARGS   Files with the given ARGS applied to the given
                                FILTER are recognized as being type TYPE.
  --type-del=TYPE               Removes all filters associated with TYPE.
```

If all you want to do is add `.haml` files to the existing Ruby spec, use

```
--type-add=ruby:ext:haml
```

If you want to see how existing types are defined, use `--dump`.

```
$ ack --dump | ack ruby
  --type-add=ruby:ext:rb,rhtml,rjs,rxml,erb,rake,spec
  --type-add=ruby:firstlinematch:/^#!.*\bruby/
  --type-add=ruby:is:Rakefile
```